# Calling a function inside a function but the terminal treats the function call as a globalname

Tags: python, scope

The task at hand is to be able to return the bitwise AND and bitwise OR from a bitstring. Everything seems to be okay but my immediate problem has to do with calling my first function into the other two.
I tried solving changing the code and came up with different variable names but nothing changed the error seen in the terminal. I also tried `if __name__ == __'main'__:` but nothing has changed as well. I've been researching all day but still have not solved the issue. Here is my code:

```
class BitOperator(object):

    def bitOperator(self,bit1,bit2):
    #Start writing your code from here
        self.bit1 = bit1
        self.bit2 = bit2

        len1 = len(bit1)
        len2 = len(bit2)

        if len1 < len2:
            bit1 = (len2 - len1) * '0' + bit1
            len1 = len2
        elif len2 < len1:
            bit2 = (len1 - len2) * '0' + bit2
            len2 = len1
        return len1, bit1, bit2

    def OperationAND(self, _bit1, _bit2):
        _bit1, _bit2, _len = self.bitOperator(_bit1, _bit2)
        self._bit1 = _bit1
        self._bit2 = _bit2
        res = ""
        for i in range(_len):
            res += str(int(_bit1[i])) & str(int(_bit2[i]))
        return res

    finalresult = OperationAND('10001', '11011')
```

In the terminal, what I get is this message: `NameError: global name 'bitOperator' is not defined` Out of ideas and would be grateful for some help.

With help my old issue is gone. After adding self.bitOperator to my other function I have a new problem. `line 43, in BitOperator finalresult = OperationAND('10001', '11011') TypeError: OperationAND() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`. Could I get a bit more guidance?

Comment: You're inside a class definition, so perhaps you meant to say `self.bitOperator`?

Comment: For debugging help, please provide a [mre] including the full error message. Most of the code here is irrelevant to the problem. For example, `OperationAND` and `OperationOR` are exactly the same as far as this error is concerned, so remove one.

Comment: You forgot `self` as the first argument to the second and third functions.

Comment: After you add the missing `self` argument to the two methods, you need to use it in them to call `self.bitOperator()`

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the reply. I don't think I get how to use it in the method as I thought I already had been doing that. I updated my work.

Comment: TreeJ: In your updated code, the `finalresult = OperationAND('10001', '11011')` statement isn't inside of any class method, so there's no `self` argument. I started to fix that but then encountered (unrelated) problems with what the other two methods are doing. No sure why you're defining a class to do this…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to fix the problem you were having with the `finalresult = OperationAND('10001', '11011')` statement, which was to remove it from the `class` definition, as well has a few other bugs I encountered in the process of doing so.

Below is final result with `# ALL CAP COMMENTS` indicating everthing I changed (I think).

```
class BitOperator(object):

    def bitOperator(self, bit1, bit2):
        self.bit1 = bit1
        self.bit2 = bit2

        len1 = len(bit1)
        len2 = len(bit2)

        if len1 < len2:
            bit1 = (len2 - len1) * '0' + bit1
            len1 = len2
        elif len2 < len1:
            bit2 = (len1 - len2) * '0' + bit2
            len2 = len1

        return bit1, bit2, len1  # THESE WERE BEING RETURNED IN WRONG ORDER

    def operationAND(self, _bit1, _bit2):
        _bit1, _bit2, _len = self.bitOperator(_bit1, _bit2)

        self._bit1 = _bit1
        self._bit2 = _bit2
        res = ""
        for i in range(_len):
            res += str(int(_bit1[i]) & int(_bit2[i]))  # CORRECTED EXPRESSION.
        return res

#    finalresult = operationAND('10001', '11011')  # REMOVED FROM CLASS DEFINITION.


# ADDED THIS SECTION TO ILLUSTRATE USE OF CLASS.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    bitoper = BitOperator()  # Create instance of class.
    finalresult = bitoper.operationAND('10001', '11011')
    print(finalresult)  # -> 10001
```